# Powershell Help, the code i have sends a email out to people, need to save a the data of the code but not as a text file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am new to powershell and need some help. I have a code which runs everyday and sends an email out to people regarding the server status and other details. What i need to do is save that file as maybe an output file or something so if the customer wants can go in to powershell type in the script command and it comes up with the information thats on the email

Is there a way to do this. This cant be a text file. Has to be something u can type and the data comes up?

please help, thanks in advance

Os

Comment: You need to "save that file as maybe an output file or something," but "cant be a text file?"  I'm confused as to what you're asking for help with.  Are you saying that it simply can't be in plaintext format, and needs to be encoded in some way?

Comment: Hi, please provide some code for us to help you with.

Answer (score 0):

Without code the only definite answer I can give you is using the `Out-File` command. I do not see why it can't be a txt file (because it's just an email)since data can come up and be typed. You can always `Out-File` to excel or csv, it really all depends on what you're trying to ask.